# Labelling the edges in a graph with python igraph

Tags: python, igraph

I have the adjacency matrix (i.e. a collection of weights) of a directed graph, and I would like to add labels (corresponding to the values of the weights) on the edges in the final plot.
In other words, I would like to obtain something like [this](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2b/Markovkate_01.svg).
I'm using python igraph, and my code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import igraph as ig


N = 6

adj_matr = np.random.random((N, N))

g = ig.Graph.Weighted_Adjacency(adj_matr.tolist(), mode=ig.ADJ_DIRECTED, attr="weight", loops=True)

ig.plot(g, "My_Graph.svg", vertex_label=map(str, np.arange(N)))
```

I have figured out how to set labels on the nodes, but I cannot find anything concrete about the edges (adding `edge_label=...` in the plot command doesn't work). Do you know how to fix the problem? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What Version are you using? There was a commit that added support for edge labels 4 month ago:  https://github.com/igraph/igraph/commit/ab936ebd7aaaf51261a94a7ba9bc5d85ca967169

Comment: Oh I see, I'm using an old version. For this reason the solutions I found didn't work.

Comment: Since the new version 0.7 is not available yet, how could I fix the problem?

Comment: You could check if the changes made it into the 0.6.7-pre that you can find here: https://github.com/igraph/igraph/releases

Comment: Alternatively, try installing a nightly build from http://igraph.org/nightly . The `setup.py` installer in the Python version should be smart enough now to download the corresponding C core automatically.

Comment: +1 didn´t know that there were nightly build! Great, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

using `vertex_label=` is equivalent to `g.vs=`

so to label your edges, use `g.es=`:

```
g.es["label"] = ["A", "B", "C"]
```

or

```
g.es["name"] = map(str, np.arange(N))
```

Comment: @IanPhillips it works for me.
check it out in the docs: http://hal.elte.hu/~nepusz/development/igraph/tutorial/tutorial.html#setting-and-retrieving-attributes

Comment: Are you using v0.7 or above? As soon as I updated to 0.7, the edge labels appeared. Also, the docs you link to don't appear to say anything about edge labels at first glance, only vertex labels.

Comment: in the docs i linked to:

  `>>> g.es["is_formal"] = [False, False, True, True, True, False, True, False, False]`